# what can cause "b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 22" error?

Tags: apache-storm

I have deployed Apache Storm version 0.9.6 on cluster of 4 virtual machines. I'm using kafka spout to read data from kafka brokers. I'm deploying both kafka brokers and storm nodes on the same virtual machines. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 23 to Netty-Client-02.novalocal/208.113.164.115:6700 failed:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: 02.novalocal/208.113.164.115:6700
```

I would like to know what is the cause of this error? I don't get it when with a local cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that it is trying to connect to the public IP address instead of the internal? I would expect that the IP starts with 192.168 or 10.10. To verify you can connect to the IP/port number, just open a telnet connection against it.

Comment: I was able to telnet and ping the IP address